# How to get the all the values in multiple columns and store them in one variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the values of 4 columns (N, P, R, T) and store them in one column.
Also, I thought of doing the same thing but for rows ( So like concatenate 4 cells in 4 columns and store them in a variable via a for loop). I think I would start doung that when I figure the columns first.

for example:-

[image]

so here i want to store the values of each column and store them in one variable and then sum all 4 values to get the value of all four columns which is (14+12+11+7) which is 44.

I wrote this code but it doesn't seem to me like its storing the values.

```
function percentage(){

  const thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(THIS).getSheetByName('WP_Data');
 var range=thisSheet.getRangeList(['N3:N', 'P3:P', 'R3:R', 'T3:T']);
 var rangeN= thisSheet.getRange("N3:N");
 var valueN=rangeN.getValues();
 var rangeP= thisSheet.getRange("P3:P");
 var valueP=rangeP.getValues();
 var rangeR= thisSheet.getRange("R3:R");
 var valueR=rangeR.getValues();
 var rangeT= thisSheet.getRange("T3:T");
 var valueT=rangeT.getValues();
 console.log()
 var val =valueN + valueP + valueR + valueT; 


}
```

would really appreciate the help.

If you need more info please let me know

Comment: You mean sum them?

Comment: yes, I will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function percentage(){

  const thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(THIS).getSheetByName('WP_Data');
  var values = thisSheet.getRange(3,14,thisSheet.getLastRow()-2,7).getValues(); // N3:T??
  var results = [];
  var i = 0;
  for( i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
    results.push([values[i][0]+values[i][2]+values[i][4]+values[i][6]]); // index 0 = column N, etc.
  }
  // don't know what you want to do with it but you could use setValues(results)
  thisSheet.getRange(??,??,results.length,1).setValues(results);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in that case the result would be an array that would store the 4 cells concatenated. What I'm looking for is just one variable that would store one number (not an array) and that number is the sum of all the values in result.

Answer (score 3):

This might do the works for you

```
function percentage(){

    const thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(THIS).getSheetByName('WP_Data');

    var range=ss.getRangeList(['N3:N', 'P3:P', 'R3:R', 'T3:T']);
    var rangeN= ss.getRange("N3:N");
    var valueN=rangeN.getValues();
    var rangeP= ss.getRange("P3:P");
    var valueP=rangeP.getValues();
    var rangeR= ss.getRange("R3:R");
    var valueR=rangeR.getValues();
    var rangeT= ss.getRange("T3:T");
    var valueT=rangeT.getValues();
    //you can use concat or creat a new array to store these values.
    const array = valueN.concat(valueP,valueR,valueT).flat();
    //then use array.reduce function to sum all the items in the array.
    const sum = array.reduce((value,sum) => value+sum)
    // you will get the out put as 44
    console.log(sum)

}
```

Is that what you asking for?

```
const string = array.toString();
console.log(string)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying it out but the value of sum is an array. I want it to be just one value that has the sum of all of them. Can you edit tat please if possible?